# Visual Studio 2013 licence information

Tags: visual-studio-2013, licensing

How can I get information on my Visual Studio 2013 Pro license.

I want to know if I can install on another computer with the same license?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information here, on Microsoft's whitepaper on licensing:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350

Visual Studio is licensed per user. You can install on another computer with the same licence as long as they are both used by you only.